# Finding the matrix representation of a linear operator $T$ for $T(f(x))=2(f(x))-f'(x)$ in $\mathbb{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Using the standard basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ gives me a matrix however it doesn't work when working towards Jordan Canonical Form with the matrix.  What I get is 
$\begin{pmatrix} 
2  \\
0 \\ 
0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
-1  \\
2 \\ 
0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
0  \\
-2 \\ 
2\end{pmatrix}$
 as my columns.  Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? That seems like a reasonable matrix for the operator.

Comment: @B.Mehta when I go to find Jordan canonical form it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix representation for the operator $T$ is correct. This operator has 2 as eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity 3, but geometric multiplicity 1. In other words: the eigenspace has dimension one and the matrix is *not* diagonalizable. Thus the Jordan normal form is:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$